# Recommendation for good cost/benefit vga for Windows Areo

Tags: hardware-rec, aero, pci-express, windows-experience-index

I want to buy a PCI express card for my PC. All Windows experience scores are good, but the onboard VGA got `1.0` in Vista experience for Aero. I've looked in the listing o video cards, and it's enormous with great price variations and models. I would like a good car to show Aero effects (like transparent windows, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any video card that is marketed as a **DirectX 9** or **DirectX 10** compatible card will be able to run Aero without any problems.

Microsoft recommends the following for the graphics card on a **Vista Premium Ready PC**:

> A DirectX 9 compatible graphics
>   processor with a Windows Display
>   Driver Model (WDDM) driver, Pixel
>   shader 2.0 in hardware, and a minimum
>   of 128 MB of Video RAM

You can choose a graphics card from the [Vista hardware compatibility list](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/Browse.aspx?type=Hardware&category=Graphics%20Cards%20%26%20Components&subcategory=Graphics%20Cards).

Answer (score 1):

This is very subjective question, because one person == one recommendation.

I preffered nVidia.

Read some webs where is comparison of graphic cards.

- [Tom's Hardware - Performance Charts Graphics Cards](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/graphics-cards,1.html)

And go to your favorite eshop with computer components and chose.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't play games, just buy something around the bottom of the pile. nVidia GeForce 8400 or similar.

In Australia they're about $60 so in the U.S.of.A they're probably about $3. I see you're in Brazil however so I don't quite know how that will affect local pricing!

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of use, just buy the cheapest nvidia or ATI card, should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had an nVidia 7200GS before and it's adequate for Aero and minimal gaming. Though you should steer clear of it if you're planning to do any serious gaming.